# Original array changed without any modifications done

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicate objects from an array, and keep only the objects which have the highest `nb` value.

**Example:**

From this array:

```
let arr = [
      {id: 1, nb: 1},
      {id: 1, nb: 4},
      {id: 2, nb: 1},
      {id: 3, nb: 1},
      {id: 1, nb: 2},
      {id: 1, nb: 3},
      {id: 2, nb: 7},
      {id: 2, nb: 8},
    ];
```

I am supposed to get this:

```
arr2 = [
   { id: 1, nb: 4 },
   { id: 2, nb: 8 }, 
   { id: 3, nb: 1 }
]
```

The algorithm below is very correct in theory, however I see the original array is modified by the end (see the last `console.log(arr)` below):

*Code:*

```
let arr = [
  {id: 1, nb: 1},
  {id: 1, nb: 4},
  {id: 2, nb: 1},
  {id: 3, nb: 1},
  {id: 1, nb: 2},
  {id: 1, nb: 3},
  {id: 2, nb: 7},
  {id: 2, nb: 8},
];
// Original array
console.log(arr);

let tmp = {};
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if( !tmp[arr[i].id] ) {
    tmp[arr[i].id] = arr[i];     
  } else {
    if (tmp[arr[i].id].nb < arr[i].nb ) {
      tmp[arr[i].id].nb = arr[i].nb;
    }
  }     
}

var result = Object.values(tmp);
// This output the desired result
console.log(result);
// Why the original array changed ?
console.log(arr);
```

This will output:

```
> Array [Object { id: 1, nb: 1 }, Object { id: 1, nb: 4 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 1 }, Object { id: 3, nb: 1 }, Object { id: 1, nb: 2 }, Object { id: 1, nb: 3 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 7 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 8 }]
> Array [Object { id: 1, nb: 4 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 8 }, Object { id: 3, nb: 1 }]
> Array [Object { id: 1, nb: 4 }, Object { id: 1, nb: 4 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 8 }, Object { id: 3, nb: 1 }, Object { id: 1, nb: 2 }, Object { id: 1, nb: 3 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 7 }, Object { id: 2, nb: 8 }]
```

Why did the original array changed when there is no processing on it apart from looping?

Comment: `tmp[arr[i].id] = arr[i];` is assigning a reference, hence `tmp[arr[i].id].nb = arr[i].nb;` is changing arr[i] indirectly. I would suggest you to make a deep copy of the original array and use it instead. `let _copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));` Then, use `_copy` instead of `arr` in your process.

Comment: looks like the same question ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/52160379

Comment: Not the same, but it follows it

Comment: with different accounts?

Comment: @NinaScholz how on Earth did you find that. That's impressive.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, long time ago I did not deal with his, forgot the basics @briosheje

Comment: @briosheje, it's just the strange wording: *remove* ... *keep* ... what is the real question?

Comment: I will edit later once home to make this clearer, thans @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because objects in both the arrays are sharing the same reference.

You will need to update from

```
tmp[arr[i].id] = arr[i];
```

to

```
tmp[arr[i].id] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[i]));
```

```js
let arr = [
  {id: 1, nb: 1},
  {id: 1, nb: 4},
  {id: 2, nb: 1},
  {id: 3, nb: 1},
  {id: 1, nb: 2},
  {id: 1, nb: 3},
  {id: 2, nb: 7},
  {id: 2, nb: 8},
];

let tmp = {};
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if( !tmp[arr[i].id] ) {
    tmp[arr[i].id] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[i]));     
  } else {
    if (tmp[arr[i].id].nb < arr[i].nb ) {
      tmp[arr[i].id].nb = arr[i].nb;
    }
  }     
}

var result = Object.values(tmp);
console.log(arr); // original array unchanged
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

The original array is updated at last as the objects in your `tmp` map and `arr` share the  same object reference. So changes made in `tmp` will be reflected in `arr`. You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to make them point to separate reference. Try the following:

```js
let arr = [ {id: 1, nb: 1}, {id: 1, nb: 4}, {id: 2, nb: 1}, {id: 3, nb: 1}, {id: 1, nb: 2}, {id: 1, nb: 3}, {id: 2, nb: 7}, {id: 2, nb: 8}, ];


let tmp = {};
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if( !tmp[arr[i].id] ) {
    tmp[arr[i].id] = Object.assign({},arr[i]);     
  } else {
    if (tmp[arr[i].id].nb < arr[i].nb ) {
      tmp[arr[i].id].nb = arr[i].nb;
    }
  }     
}

var result = Object.values(tmp);
console.log(result)
```